# add field first_name and last_name in django-profile

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I need  add the `first_name` and `last_name` fields associated with
 that `User` model and display it in the profile `form`.

***fields:***

```
   >>> user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
   >>> user.first_name
       u'Some'
   >>> user.last_name
       u'User'
```

***My model is something like this :***

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
  personal_email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
  address = models.CharField(max_length=140)
  phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)

  def __unicode__(self):
      return u'Profile of user: %s' % self.user.username
```

when rendering the profile form, would have to show the fields.

```
first_name:  
last_name: 
personal_email:  
address: 
phone_number:
```

**Edit**

*I resolved to*:

#forms.py

> ```py
> class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
>     first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
>     last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
>
>     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
>         super(UserProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
>         self.fields['first_name'].initial = self.instance.user.first_name
>         self.fields['last_name'].initial = self.instance.user.last_name
>
>         self.fields.keyOrder = [
>             'first_name',
>             'last_name',
>             'personal_email',
>             'address',
>             'phone_number',
>             ]
>
>
>     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
>         super(UserProfileForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
>         self.instance.user.first_name = self.cleaned_data.get('first_name')   
>         self.instance.user.last_name = self.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
>         self.instance.user.save()
>
>     class Meta:
>         model = UserProfile
> ```

#urls.py

> ```
>      url(r'^profiles/edit/', edit_profile, {'form_class': UserProfileForm},
>                                              name='profiles_edit_profile'  ),
> ```

and add in #signals.py

```
    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            userprofile, new = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using a ModelForm you could do the following:

```
class profileForm(ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False)
    last_name  = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile

    def save(self, commit=True):
        m = super(customerForm, self).save(commit=False)
        # Update and save user model here
        if commit:
            m.save()
        return m
```

You could skip overriding the save methods and do the save in your view. Just get get the first and last name value and save it after you validate the form. You might also want to used a transaction to make sure everything saves or nothing does.

Comment: in this way would have to make a `views` and create a `urls`?