# How to update User object without creating new one?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Following works fine in shell:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> user=User.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> user.first_name = u'Some'
>>> user.last_name = u'Name'
>>> user.save()
>>> user.first_name
u'Some'
>>> user.last_name
u'Name'
```

Then I try to do the same with forms:

```
# forms.py
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']


# views.py
def edit_names(request, template_name="registration/edit_names.html"):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.save()
            url = urlresolvers.reverse('my_account')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    else:
        form = UserForm(instance=request.user)
    page_title = _('Edit user names')
    return render_to_response(template_name, locals(),
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))

# edit_names.html
<form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {{ form.as_table }}
        <tr><td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" />
        </td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

I open page in browser and see two fields `First name` and `Last name`. When I fill in the fields and submit the form I get the error:

```
 Exception Type:    IntegrityError
Exception Value:    column username is not unique
```

I also tried to add `['username']` to fields list in UserForm. If I submit the form with my username (as request.user), the form displays errormessage:

```
User with this Username already exists.
```

If I change the username to some unique name, the new user with that username is being created.

The question is:
**How can I update User object, not create new one?**

Sorry for being so verbose, but I had hard search here and could not find the answer to my question.

BTW, these cases don't work for me:

- [Extending UserCreationForm to include email, first name, and last name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910769/extending-usercreationform-to-include-email-first-name-and-last-name)
- [add field first_name and last_name in django-profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085452/add-field-first-name-and-last-name-in-django-profile)
- [How to create a UserProfile form in Django with first_name, last_name modifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727564/how-to-create-a-userprofile-form-in-django-with-first-name-last-name-modificati)

**EDIT:**

As suggested @fceruti I just added on request.method == 'post' branch this:

```
form = UserForm(data=request.POST, instance=request.user)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just add on request.method == 'post' branch this:

```
form = UserForm(data=request.POST, instance=request.user)
```

Comment: There won't be a `request.user` if this is a sign up form

Comment: OMG! That simple!
I've spent oodles of time trying to find whats wrong :((

Thank you a lot! Sorry I can't vote up for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
if request.method == "POST":
    kwargs = { 'data' : request.POST }
    try:
        kwargs['instance'] = User.objects.get(username=request.POST['username'])
    except:
        pass
    form = UserForm(kwargs**)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        ...
```

Comment: This version also works, thanks for you help! Except one moment: I think double asterisk should go before kwargs
`form = UserForm(**kwargs)`

Comment: This way will cause an extra DB lookup so @fceruti solution is much better in this situation. This way is useful to know for other instances though