# Django CMS - Clients Account

Tags: python, django, django-cms, user-accounts

I'm new to python and Django CMS.

I want to create a website where users can log in and update their own profile information, but cannot edit the website. I'm just wondering if it's possible to integrate an account system in Django CMS.

If yes, how?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this only you want to update the profile ? You can create a form.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the reply. It's more like a course website. The users can see their grades and course enrollment status. The owner of the service can update the users' stats. Could you specify how can I create this form? Do you have a reference or a link?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37453821/django-user-update-form-and-view  
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/
Hope this helps. Let's come the other people on this.